# Notice: Undefined index with while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, undefined-index

I'm receiving the following error in php: `Notice: Undefined index: panel_num`.

I think I need to use `isset()` but I can't seem to get it to work with `while`

```
global $d;
$i = 1;
while($i <= $d['panel_num']){
$options[] = array(
                      "name" => "Panel".$i,
                        "id" => "panel_".$i,
                       "std" => "",
                      "type" => "panel");
$i++;
}
```

What is the proper way to resolve this issue?

Comment: The array `$d` obviously doesn't contain what you expect it to.  `print_r($d)` to see what's actually in there, and if the `panel_num` key doesn't exist, either bail out of the operation or use a default value instead.

Comment: What's in `$d`? do a `var_dump($d)` and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to check for [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and not [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) `$d['panel_num']`

```
global $d;
if(isset($d['panel_num']) && !empty($d['panel_num']))
{
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= $d['panel_num']){
    $options[] = array(
                  "name" => "Panel".$i,
                    "id" => "panel_".$i,
                   "std" => "",
                  "type" => "panel");
    $i++;
    }
}
```

So you will avoid to call your variable if it is not set or it's empty

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if that variable is set before using it:

```
global $d;
if (isset($d['panel_num']))
{
  $i = 1;
  while($i <= $d['panel_num']){
  $options[] = array(
                      "name" => "Panel".$i,
                        "id" => "panel_".$i,
                       "std" => "",
                      "type" => "panel");
  $i++;
  }
}
```